# how to run two apps on EC2 with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, nginx, amazon-ec2, production-environment

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and generally server side and I have created a Rails app and have deployed it on Ubuntu Ec2.
I am using Nginx and Thin server on it.The app is running perfectly on it.

Now I want to deploy another app on the same server.
I have already put the app on the server and when i try to start the rails app it does not start.
I guess it is because of nginx.conf file.

Can someone please let me know how to run two apps on the same server

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not start'? is there an error? what is it?

Comment: @UriAgassi no i mean i did thin start -s 4 -e production -p 3020 ...But the site is not generated

Comment: By not generated you mean you cannot surf to it? Can you reach it from within the machine (`curl localhost:3020`)? Did you open the port on the security group?

Comment: It is giving me Html template in response..But when visit the url in browser ,It Keeps loading(no output)

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/nginx/2018/08/20/installing-and-configuration-of-nginx-web-reverse-proxy-server-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to browse to a machine on Amazon's EC2, and you don't get any response, the best suspect is the [AWS Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). Make sure that the port the application runs on is open in your machine's security group:

[image: Security group screen]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/images/Console_Security_Group_Add_Rule.png))</sub>

For nginx to run both you apps, you need to configure them both on its `nginx.conf`

```
upstream app1 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream app2 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3020;
}
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name .example.com;

  access_log /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/error.log;
  root     /var/www/myapp.example.com;
  index    index.html;

  location /app1 {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://app1;
  }

  location /app2 {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://app2;
  }
}
```

This configuration will listen for `app1` on local port 3000, and `app2` on local port 3020, and redirect data starting with `http://my.example.com/app1` to the first app, and data starting with `http://my.example.com/app2` to the second app.

Comment: Do we have to make changes in nginx conf to run two apps..Dont think it is related to security issues

Comment: If you want to run both apps under nginx then yes, but for running thin on a different port - nginx won't be a problem

Comment: @uri-agassi..Yes i do want to run both apps under nginx and thin

Comment: You want to run them on different ports (`http://my.domain.com/` and `http://my.domain.com:3020`) or different paths (`http://my.domain.com/app1/...` and `http://my.domain.com/app2`)?

Comment: It will be better to run on different path i guess

Comment: Added a config example. Tell me if that works for you.

Comment: will try out and let u know

Comment: we run the apps on different ports.your above config exampled helped me.